# What is this plumbing "temperature regulator" called, and how do I adjust it?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I was told the below restricts/governs how much hot water can make it to my tub/shower.  I'd like to know what it's called, and how I can adjust it to get hotter water.

[image]

I'm attempting to twist the "cap" (the beige-ish color) to the right, but am meeting more resistance than I would have expected (having no knowledge of how it works).  I'm afraid to attempt to turn too hard for fear that it is not what I'm supposed to adjust, and I could break/crack the pipe.

Or do I need to find an alan wrench or similar to adjust just the little silver deal at the top?

Comment: I'd call it a "tempering valve" used to stop the outlet water being any higher than a set point.  In my country they're mandatory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Thermostatic Mixing Valve](http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=6842)

According to the [installation instructions (PDF)](http://media.wattswater.com/1915906.pdf)

> [image]
>
> 1. Let the water flow for at least two minutes to allow supply temperature to stabilize.
> 2. Calibrate the mixed water outlet temperature by placing a thermometer in the mixed water stream.
> 3. To adjust the setting of the valve, loosen locking cap screw with hex wrench, see Figure 4. Cap must be lifted 1/4" to adjust temperature. To increase the temperature, turn counter clockwise. To decrease temperature turn clockwise.
> 4. Lower handle and tighten screw.
> 5. Check outlet temperature.